# Regev PKE not CPA secure for specific $A$?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, provable-security, chosen-plaintext-attack, lwe

I encountered notes stating that, for certain fixed $A$, such as $A \in M_{n\log(q)\times n}$ as follows:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
2 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
4 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
&\dots\\
2^{\log(q)-1} & 0 & 0 &\dots \\
0 & 1 & 0 &\dots\\
0 & 2 & 0 &\dots\\
0 & 4 & 0 &\dots\\
&\dots\\
0 & 2^{\log(q)-1} & 0 &\dots\\
&\dots\\
\end{bmatrix}

(where for simplicity of representation, it is assumed that $q$ is a power of $2$), the Regev encryption scheme is not CPA secure.

I've been trying to prove this, but I seem to be missing something crucial. Specifically, I thought that, perhaps knowing $A$, one wold be able to solve for $s$ using unit vectors for the encryption instead of random ones, but that didn't yield anything. I couldn't come up with other forms of encryption that would inform of the CPA challenger's choice.

Specifically, I thought of creating encryptions of $0$ using unit vectors $u_i$ as such: $(u_i^TA, u_i^Tb)$ (where $b=As+e$). With this, for $u_1$, for example, we get: $(u_1, s_1+e_1)$, so we know the value of $s_1+e_1$ as a result of the encryption. This doesn't seem to facilitate solving for $s_i, e_i$ though.

What am I missing?

Note: I have also added the FHE tag because this matrix reminds me of the FHE scheme to reduce the error size.

Comment: Hint: you can indeed solve for $s$ (and the error $e$). Do you see how to recover, say, the least-significant bit of $s_1$ (i.e., whether it is odd or even)?

Comment: @ChrisPeikert Still unsuccessful... :/ I just get equations of the form $s_1 +e_1=c_1$, $2s_1 +e_2=c_2$ etc. ($c_i$ is the second element in the encryption tuple) when I use unit vectors instead of random ones. So this yields a system of equations that has one-too-many variables in order to solve (so far we have 2 equations with three variables).

Comment: @ChrisPeikert Perhaps looking for $s$ in binary form somehow? If $s$ is binary, then knowing that $e$ is roughly $0$ means that a result of $c_1<\frac{q}{4}$ (e.g.) yields that $s_1$ is $0$ and vice versa.

Comment: What is the relevant equation you are trying to solve? If this is to be useful to others, you should state it in the question . Is it something like $As+e=y$ given $y$?

Comment: @kodlu I have added more details on the equations I mentioned.

Comment: I'm now thinking that perhaps the same encryptions for $1$ (which add $\frac{q}{2}$ to the second term) would now yield a solvable system of equations? Is that right?

Comment: Think about the equation $2^{\ell}s_1 + e_ell = c_\ell$ for $\ell = 2^{\log q-1}$, where $\e_\ell$ is “small.”